# How to register as an admin in Django app using Registration Model and Views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-registration

I am familiar with creating a `superuser` in a Django App using `python manage.py createsuperuser` command in terminal. I am also familiar with creating a superuser using Python Shell.

But I want to know that how do we register a user as an admin in a Django App using `RegistrationModel` and `views.py`? Or more specifically, how to register the user and change it's status to `staff` or `superuser` in `views.py`?

Comment: The same way as in the Django shell.

Comment: You've to provide some code while registering user you've to set `is_superuser` flag **True**

Answer (score 0):

## STEP ONE

After creating and activating virtual environment
Let's create our new project (authentication) and a new app (users) using the following command

```
    $ django-admin startproject authentication . 
    $ python manage.py startapp users
```

Next is we add *users* app to *installed_apps* in *authentication/settings.py* file

## STEP TWO

We create *CustomUser* model in our *users/urls.py* file

```
    #users/urls.py
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
    from django.urls import reverse

    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        pass

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("login_page", args=[str(self.id)])
```

In other to alert *django* to use the *CustomUser* model for authentication, we add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'` to our *authentication/settings.py* file

## STEP THREE

Create a new file *forms.py* in **users** app and add the following

```
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
    from .models import CustomUser

    class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
        class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
            model = CustomUser
            fields = [
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'username',
                'email',
                'password1',
                'password2',
                'is_staff',
                'is_superuser',
            ]
        
    class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
        class Meta:
            model = CustomUser
            fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

## STEP FOUR

Since we customized our `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm`, we have to update in our *users/admin.py* file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    list_display = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
        ]    

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

## STEP FOUR

We can proceed to making migrations and migrating the tables to database using the command

```
    $ python manage.py makemigrations
    $ python manage.py migrate
```

## STEP FIVE

Create the template for creating new **users**. We create a new folder (`templates`) in our parent dir where we can store our `html` files and create a new file `create_new.html` in the `templates` folder

Command for this:

```
    $ mkdir templates
    $ touch templates/create_new.html
```

Update the templates settings

```
    # authentication/settings.py
    TEMPLATES:
         'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates']  # new
```

Add the following to *templates/create_new.html* file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
        <title>New admin</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create new user" />
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

## STEP SIX

Create view to display this template

```
    # users/views.py
    from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
    from .models import CustomUser
    from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

    class UserCreateView(CreateView):
        model = CustomUser
        template_name = 'create_new.html'
        form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
```

## STEP SEVEN

Link view to a specific *url*

```
    # authentication/urls.py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include # new

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls,),
        path('', include('users.urls')), # new
    ]
```

```
#user/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

## STEP EIGHT

Run local server and create new user to login to the admin-site. *No need of `python manage.py createsuperuser` command